Chrome extension Error Invalid value for 'permissions[0]'. Manifest.json
I've been trying to make a chrome extension but keep running into the same problem over and over again when trying to load it in chrome.
Error Invalid value for 'permissions[0]'. Could not load manifest.
Manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Jumbo Cart Extractor",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Extracts shopping cart data from Jumbo website.",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "https://www.jumbo.com/"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.jumbo.com/*"],
            "js": ["js/content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "js/background.js"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": [
                "images/icon16.png",
                "images/icon48.png",
                "images/icon128.png",
                "popup.html",
                "js/content.js",
                "js/background.js"
            ],
            "matches": [
                "*://www.jumbo.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

